# Signed JWT between Java microservices

Tags: java, jwt, microservices

I need a service to talk securely to other services over HTTPS, and I would like to do with a signed JWT.

Whats a good Java framework to generate, sign and validate a JWT?
And more importantly how do I safely manage a secret or key pair?

Or maybe there is another (better) approach to achieve the above?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think that Spring Boot is a very good option for you. You can use Spring Security module to generate and refresh the JWT. You can read about it [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt).

About the key pair, I don't have such experience as JWT but I think that [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate) can help you.

To learn about Java and Spring, Baeldung is a very good site.